# Scan dependency-jars for 'phoning home'?

Tags: java, maven, security, networking, jar

Recently we found a jar in our application phoning home. See details: https://github.com/nextgenhealthcare/connect/issues/3431)

This is very undesired behaviour.

What would be the best approach to detect this in one of our depedencies?

ps. I can unzip all the jars and scan for `HttpClient` or `UrlConnection`, but there are many ways to connect to external systems, and preferably I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

I am aware of the OWASP Dependency-Check, but phoning home is not a CVE per se.

Answer (score 1):

If you scan your jar's, and they do have network connectivity, then what can do then? You can't recompile the source, as you don't have it. A case of finding something you can do nothing about (apart from find an alternative).

The only way is it firewall your application, or network, use containers, and have a fine grained control of what you application talk to. Basically run your jars with zero trust!

I guess it really boils down to trusting your jar files, and that means in turn trusting the humans that make that everything that goes into jar file. (design, coding, build, distribution, maintenance ). The whole SDLC

If you approach the problem of zero trust, you can either get the JVM (security manager), The operating system (SELINUX/System Cap's/Docker) or the network (firewall/proxy/ids) (or all three) to control and audit access attempts..and either deny or permit these access depending on a policy that you set.

Scanning the jars for network calls can be done, but i'm sure if a jar *really* wants to obfuscate it's network behaviour, it will be able to, especially if it can run shell commands, or dynamically load jar's itself.

A jar you scan today, might not have the same behaviour on the next update? The classic supply chain attack.

If you don't trust you jar's, then if you must establish that trust, either thought scanning, auditing the source code.

There are many tools for this. I'm not sure if i'm allowed to recommend a particular product here that i've had success with, so i won't.

Comment: *If you scan your jar's, and they do have network connectivity, then what can do then?* - exclude them and find repleacement libraries.

Comment: But I think the container based approach might be the best way